What are the relevant specs for a BLDC fan controller?
I have a ceiling fan with a fried remote receiver / controller that I need to replace. Oddly enough, the only specs I am able to discern are power limit (original says 38W, I can find plenty of similar spec'd ones) and BLDC (3 wire) vs DC or AC. No voltage, no amps, nothing about the number of rotor/stator pairs, etc.. Is this really irrelevant / standardised? Does the number of speeds that the remote can set have anything to do with the fan?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please specify what do you have and what do you want to do clearly.
